# How to remove a char from a string, and return a number from the new string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, binary, return

I have a few functions that aim to convert a user input as a string to a binary number. This is part of a basic 'assembler' program I am working on. Here is my code:

```
    function generateBinaryNumber(inputValue) //only works for hash!
{
    var number;

    if(containsHash(inputValue) != -1)
    {
        number = getNumberFromString(inputValue);
    }

    return decimalToBinary(number);
}

function containsHash(number) //Working!
{
    var n = number.indexOf('#');
    return n;
}

function getNumberFromString(mixedInput) //Working!
{
    return (mixedInput.replace('#',''));
}

function decimalToBinary(decimal) //Working!
{
    decimal = parseInt(decimal);
    return decimal.toString(2);
}
```

If a user enters a value of '5' for example, the function returns NaN - however if they specify #5 it works - 101 is returned. I am new to programming and Javascript, if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the input if there's no `#`

```
function generateBinaryNumber(inputValue) //only works for hash!
{
    var number; //number is not set

    if(containsHash(inputValue) != -1) 
    {
        //number is set here, but only if the if statement is true
        number = getNumberFromString(inputValue);
    }
    //if containsHash was false, number is undefined
    return decimalToBinary(number);
}
```

You just want to say `var number=inputValue;` when you declare it

As a side note, you should also add a radix argument to your parseInt (so something like `parseInt(decimal,10)`)  otherwise it will treat input like `"010"` as hex digits and will parse it incorrectly.